# Oracle APEX 5 notifications

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

After running "Upgrade Application" utility (from v.4-style to v.5-style) some items converts to subtype, like Number Item and so on. It's really good, but there no property where to show error text. It would be very nice if ALL error messages of similar "built-in" validations appears only in notification area (green rectangle) and not near item (red rectangle). I can't found where to set it. Help please. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this at application level, by setting the property Default Error Display Location to "Inline in Notification":

[image]

Result:
[image]